# How to hide rows by specific condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple function that I made which checks the `left` quantity of a row and if it is zero then hide it if the checkbox is checked. But it doesn't work, I tried to use `.change` function but it seems to be not working.

Can anyone please check what is wrong?

```js
$("#get_zero").prop('checked')
{
    var td = $(".left_qty");
    if(td.text() == 0)
    {
        $(td).parent().hide();
    }
}

$("#get_zero").change(function(e)
{
    var td = $(".left_qty");
    if($(this).prop('checked'))
    {
        if(td.text() == 0)
        {
            $(td).parent().hide();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $(td).parent().show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in get_zero" id="get_zero" checked="checked" />
    <label for="get_zero">Show 0 Quantity Products</label>
</p>
<table class="table table-hover" id="products_table" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
  <tr style="color: #333333;">
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Name</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Category</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Nick</th>

    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Color</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Model</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">QtyIN</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">QtyOUT</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Left</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Cost</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Total</th>
    <th style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Edit/Update</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Delete</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_4">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/4/full">crown cooking rang 27m black body</a></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cooking rang</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cr</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">black</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">27m</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">18</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">16</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">2</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">13,500.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">27,000.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/4"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_4" id="del_4"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_5">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/5/full">canon cooking rang c28 steel body</a></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cooking rang</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cr2</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">steel</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">c28</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">20</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">11</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">9</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">15,000.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">135,000.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/5"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_5" id="del_5"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_6">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/6/full">stone gas billton oven 22x22</a>
    </td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">billton oven</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">bo</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">steel</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">22x22</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">6</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">6</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">0</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">8,500.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">0.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/6"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_6" id="del_6"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_7">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/7/full">Juicer Hit</a></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">Juicer</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">j1</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">white</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">j1</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">300</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">24</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">276</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">1,200.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">331,200.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/7"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_7" id="del_7"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "#get_zero". checkbox. wait silly typo.

Comment: You really should not inline css

Comment: I know that but I did that in hurry. Have any thoughts on my problem?

Comment: Try `td.parent()` instead of `$(td).parent()`. The `td` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: td.text() will return the text from all tds with that class combined into one string, so, "290276", it will only be equal to "0" if that's the only text found in all those tds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after. You want to bind a change event handler to your checkbox and when it changes, loop through the `left_qty` cells.

```js
$("#get_zero").change(function(e) {
    $('td.left_qty').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == 0 && !$("#get_zero").is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().hide()
      } else {
        $(this).parent().show()
      }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in get_zero" id="get_zero" checked="checked" />
  <label for="get_zero">Show 0 Quantity Products</label>
</p>
<table class="table table-hover" id="products_table" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
  <tr style="color: #333333;">
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Name</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Category</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Nick</th>

    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Color</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Model</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">QtyIN</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">QtyOUT</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Left</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Cost</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Total</th>
    <th style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Edit/Update</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Delete</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_4">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/4/full">crown cooking rang 27m black body</a></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cooking rang</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cr</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">black</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">27m</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">18</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">16</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">2</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">13,500.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">27,000.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/4"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_4" id="del_4"></a>

    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_5">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/5/full">canon cooking rang c28 steel body</a></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cooking rang</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cr2</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">steel</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">c28</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">20</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">11</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">9</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">15,000.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">135,000.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/5"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_5" id="del_5"></a>

    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_6">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/6/full">stone gas billton oven 22x22</a></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">billton oven</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">bo</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">steel</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">22x22</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">6</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">6</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">0</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">8,500.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">0.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/6"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_6" id="del_6"></a>

    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_7">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/7/full">Juicer Hit</a></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">Juicer</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">j1</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">white</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">j1</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">300</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">24</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">276</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">1,200.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">331,200.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/7"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_7" id="del_7"></a>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for the checked status *within* your change-event callback. Also, you need to iterate over the cells you want to check, and make the check for each of them.

You should also call the handler on page load so the initial visualisation is also consistent with the checkbox. Finally, you can use `toggle` for showing/hiding:

```js
$("#get_zero").change(function(e) {
    var show = $(this).is(':checked');
    $(".left_qty").each(function () { // Iterate over cells
        $(this).parent().toggle(show || $(this).text() != 0);
    });
}).change(); // trigger on page load also
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in get_zero" id="get_zero" checked="checked" />
      <label for="get_zero">Show 0 Quantity Products</label>
    </p>
<table class="table table-hover" id="products_table" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
  <tr style="color: #333333;">
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Name</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Category</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Nick</th>

    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Color</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Model</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">QtyIN</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">QtyOUT</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Left</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Cost</th>
    <th style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Total</th>
    <th style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Edit/Update</th>
    <th style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #000;">Delete</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_4">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/4/full">crown</a></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cooking rang</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cr</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">black</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">27m</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">18</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">16</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">2</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">13,500.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">27,000.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/4"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_4" id="del_4"></a>

    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_5">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/5/full">canon</a></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cooking rang</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">cr2</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">steel</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">c28</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">20</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">11</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">9</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">15,000.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">135,000.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/5"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_5" id="del_5"></a>

    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_6">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/6/full">stone</a></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">billton oven</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">bo</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">steel</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">22x22</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">6</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">6</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">0</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">8,500.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">0.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/6"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_6" id="del_6"></a>

    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr class="product_rows" id="tr_7">
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;"><a target="_blank" href="/report/stock/7/full">Juicer</a></td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">Juicer</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">j1</td>

    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">white</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">j1</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">300</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">24</td>
    <td class="left_qty" style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">276</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">1,200.00</td>
    <td style="border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">331,200.00</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" href="/products/edit/7"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
      <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg delete_item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#form_del_7" id="del_7"></a>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```